# How to get current 'View' from background service in android?

Tags: android, view, android-service, android-view

I want to implement print-screen kind of stuff on device shake. For that I have created one service which will start on device Boot. When I shake it I can see the custom Toast message. Now I want to do print-screen on same event. For that I required 'View' object. I have implemented print-screen using activity successfully. Now want to implement the same in service.

How to get current 'View' from background service in android?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use this:

```
HUDView mView;

 public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mView = new HUDView(this);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
        params.setTitle("Load Average");
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        wm.addView(mView, params);
        this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    }

public HUDView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ctx = context;

        mLoadPaint = new Paint();
        mLoadPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mLoadPaint.setTextSize(20);
        mLoadPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
    }
protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
something to draw
}
```

i use this to draw something ontop of every screen

Comment: Hi Boe-Dev ,    Thanks for your replay. What is HUDView..? Is it any API class or your custom class. If it is please please provide the info....

Answer (score 0):

yes it is a own class, my onDraw looks like this

```
 @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        std = canvas;
        std.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.menu), 200, std.getHeight()-50, mLoadPaint);
        }
        invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Actually I don’t want to draw anything, my concern is I want the 'View' object/reference of the topActivity (foreground Activity) from my background service.